# "The program '[XXXX] w3wp.exe: Managed' has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, iis-7.5

I am currently working on VS2012 Premium, IIS7, .Net framework 4.

I am running VS2012 as administrator.
My PC is running Windows 7 64bit

When I run my code for first time everything is OK, but for the second time the VS2012 shows an error message box "Unable to Debug".  My work around is close the VS2012 instance and open it up again.  So I ended up working in the following fashion.

1. Open VS2012
2. Load the solution
3. Debug F5
4. Close VS2012
5. Repeat from step 1

I already push & pull all the buttons under Project/Properties but so far with no luck.  This is a very unproductive way to work.

Just for let you know the problem appears some time ago, previously it was working fine.

Some suggestions?  Anybody with the same bad experience?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to put the project (web application in iis) under different (new) iis application pool.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing all instances of internet explorer before debugging.

It worked for me.

Best of luck...!!